# Loop in bash to create decimal number

Tags: bash, programming

How to generate a numbers

```
0.01, 0.02, 0.03 ... until 0.2
```

in bash ?

i run this example but it doesn't work

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Script for running several experimentations one the same JVM
#

for ((i = 0; i < 0.1; i += 0.01))
do
echo $i
done
```

Comment: bash only has integer arithmetic

Answer (score 7):

Simple and easy:

```
seq BEGIN STEP END
```

example:

```
seq 0.0 0.1 2.0
```

or (default +1)

```
for i in `seq 1 30`; do echo student$i; done
```

Answer (score 2):

The following script gives you an output like

```
0.01, 0.02, 0.03 ... until 0.2
```

/

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0; i < 20; i += 1))
do
        echo "scale=2; ${i}/100" | bc
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash can only do math with integers, not floats, so you either have to use a different language, like awk or bc, or shift the problem into integer domain.

With awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ for (i=0.0; i < 0.2; i+=0.01) printf("%.2f\n", i); }'
```

With bash, using integers

```
for ((i=0; i < 20; i++)); do
    printf "%d.%02d\n" $((i/100)) $((i%100))
done
```